# How do I change Fedora to SDDM from GDM?

Tags: fedora, sddm

I keep finding sources talking about changing the DM and DE using /etc/sysconfig/desktop but when I write this in the file, nothing changes:

```
DESKTOP="GNOME"
DISPLAYMANAGER="SDDM"
```

I have already installed sddm.

Comment: Does [disabling/enabling the display manager with `systemctl`](https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2018/fedora-switch-display-manager/) work?

Comment: @rickhg12hs It does indeed, thanks. The various distros and versions of the same seem to have quite a few ways that you have to learn to do this and I never found this simple method before. Any pointers?

Comment: I search lots of resources for info:  man pages, `man -k`, Google search (limiting time to last month/year), Stack Exchange sites (usually show up in Google searches), [Fedora docs](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/docs/), etc.  You should also know that docs/recommendations for other distros, or even older versions of Fedora, may not be appropriate/effective for your version of Fedora.  Make sure you backup anything/everything that may be affected by changes you make ... and have a plan to recover to where you started.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `systemctl` to switch to `SDDM` - first disable your current display manager. Do the switch like this:

```bsh
systemctl disable gdm
systemctl enable sddm
```

Probably easiest to reboot after this.